# Entity Framework 4 POCO generation does not resolve System.Guid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, t4

I am using the POCO generation for EF4. When the code generates for my one field that is a `Guid` I get.

```
public virtual System.Guid MyProp
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

The word `Guid` is underlined. With the error

> Cannot resolve symbol Guid

If I change the code to:

```
public virtual Guid MyProp
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Everything works fine. Hoe can I fix my problem so that the generated code does not give an error.

Comment: What is the namespace for your app? Do you have a `.System` namespace anywhere? It could be trying to resolve it to there.

Comment: ServicesModel is the name space. No name space with .System anywhere

Comment: When you mouse over Guid using Visual Studio in the second example does the pop up say 'struct System.Guid'? Does your generated POCO class not include 'using System;'? I'm pretty sure that's in the default template